# @media tag is not working within an HTML class

Tags: html, css

I have created a following CSS class

```css
.BlogCard
{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  height:550px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgb(255, 150, 150);
}
```

And the below @media tag

```css
@media  screen and (max-width: 500px) {
        body {
            background-color: lightgreen;
        }
         .Blogcard
            {
             height:50px;
             background:rgb(255, 250, 250);
            }
    }
```

While background color changes,the Blogcard dimensions remain same.
Thanks in advance

Comment: One says .BlogCard and the other says .Blogcard. There's your mistake.

Comment: You have capital C in name class.BlogCard and in @media don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it because  it is .BlogCard not .Blogcard